# How to solve the Stieltjes integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, integral-equations

If $g=g(t)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies an integral equation
$$g(t) = a + b\int_s^tg(u) du,\quad t\geq s,$$
then we have a solution
$ g(t) = a \exp{\{b(t-s)\}}.$

More generally, for an increasing and continuous function $A=A(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, let us consider an integral equation
$$ g(t) = a + b\int_s^tg(u) dA(u),\quad t\geq s$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants, and the integral is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, and $g$ is integrable w.r.t. $A$ on every interval $[s,t]$.

Then, how can I solve the equation above ? I expect it would have a solution
$$g(t) = a \exp{\{b(A(t)-A(s))\}}. $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is $C^1$. Then the equation is
$$
g(t) = a + b\int_s^tg(u)\,A'(u)\,du,\quad t\geq s. 
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ be obtain the differential equation
$$
g'(t)=b\,A'(t)\,g(t),\quad g(s)=a.
$$
Write it as $g'/g=b\,A'$ and integrate to obtain $g=C\,e^{bA}$ for some constant $C$, whose value can be found from the condition $g(s)=a$, resulting in $c=a\,e^{-bA(s)}$. finally, we get as you expected
$$
g(t)=a\,e^{b(A(t)-A(s)}.
$$

Comment: If we DON`T assume $A$ is $C^1$, can we solve the equation similarly?

Comment: The only thing I can think right now is to approximate $A$ by a sequence $A_n$ of smooth functions such that $A_n$ converges in $L^1$ to $A$, and the total variation of $A_n$ converges to the total variation of $A$.